# AngularJS double ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, jquery-ui-accordion

I'm working on accordion group and have two ng-repeat. Outer one repeats weeks from current week to a specific date. Inner repeats working hours sever days in each week.

function expand(week.id) is to call database and prepare data for variable "hour".

My problem is that when I click on one accordion-heading to show data in week#1, the rest of all other weeks(accordions) also show the same data, which makes this process very slow.

How could I just render the trs under the heading where I clicked? E.g My scenario is when I click on heading of week#1, only trs under week#1 are rendered.

Could anyone help me with this?

```
  <accordion-group   ng-repeat="week in weeks">
        <accordion-heading >
            <span ng-click="expand(week.id)">{{week.firstday}}--{{week.lastday}}</span>
        </accordion-heading>
        <table class="table table-striped">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Task</th>
                <th>Sun</th>
                <th>Mon</th>
                <th>Tue</th>
                <th>Wed</th>
                <th>Thu</th>
                <th>Fri</th>
                <th>Sat</th>
                <th>Total</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id={{week.id}}>
            <tr ng-repeat="hr in hour">

                <td> <select class="form-control input-sm" ng-disabled="false"><option value="hr.task_name">{{hr.task_name}}</option></select></td>
                <td><input type="number" min="0" ng-model="hr.sun" class="form-control"  placeholder="Hours" ng-disabled="true"></td>
                <td><input type="number" min="0" ng-model="hr.mon" class="form-control"  placeholder="Hours" ng-disabled="true"></td>
                <td><input type="number" min="0" ng-model="hr.tue" class="form-control"  placeholder="Hours" ng-disabled="true"></td>
                <td><input type="number" min="0" ng-model="hr.wed" class="form-control"  placeholder="Hours" ng-disabled="true"></td>
                <td><input type="number" min="0" ng-model="hr.thu" class="form-control"  placeholder="Hours" ng-disabled="true"></td>
                <td><input type="number" min="0" ng-model="hr.fri" class="form-control"  placeholder="Hours" ng-disabled="true"></td>
                <td><input type="number" min="0" ng-model="hr.sat" class="form-control"  placeholder="Hours" ng-disabled="true"></td>
                <td><span class="form-control">{{hr.sun+hr.mon+hr.tue+hr.wed+hr.thu+hr.fri+hr.sat}}</span></td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
         </accordion-group>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because all weeks share the same variable `hour`, expanding one heading will cause that same variable to be overwritten, modifying all panes' inner `ng-repeat` contents.

Instead, you either need to make `hour` a property on each `week` object in `weeks`, or you need to have a separate object/map that stores the array of hours against the `week.id`.

For the latter, have the following line at the start of your controller:

```
$scope.hours = {};
```

Then in your `expand()` function, instead of populating `$scope.hour`, populate `$scope.hours[weekId]`.

Finally, change your inner `ng-repeat` expression to:

```
hr in hours[week.id]
```

Answer (score 1):

hr in hour might make everything of the same model hour, in which case You need to separate the model like hr in week.hour if you can make the hour a property of week. If not you can try an ng-init like this if the hour and weeks correlate, where the hours instead of being an array of the hours that display is an array of arrays that have the display hours:

```
<accordion-group   ng-repeat="week in weeks" ng-init="weekIndex = $index">
    <accordion-heading >
        <span ng-click="expand(week.id)">{{week.firstday}}--{{week.lastday}}</span>
    </accordion-heading>
    <table class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Task</th>
            <th>Sun</th>
            <th>Mon</th>
            <th>Tue</th>
            <th>Wed</th>
            <th>Thu</th>
            <th>Fri</th>
            <th>Sat</th>
            <th>Total</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id={{week.id}}>
        <tr ng-repeat="hr in hours[weekIndex]">

            <td> <select class="form-control input-sm" ng-disabled="false"><option value="hr.task_name">{{hr.task_name}}</option></select></td>
            <td><input type="number" min="0" ng-model="hr.sun" class="form-control"  placeholder="Hours" ng-disabled="true"></td>
            <td><input type="number" min="0" ng-model="hr.mon" class="form-control"  placeholder="Hours" ng-disabled="true"></td>
            <td><input type="number" min="0" ng-model="hr.tue" class="form-control"  placeholder="Hours" ng-disabled="true"></td>
            <td><input type="number" min="0" ng-model="hr.wed" class="form-control"  placeholder="Hours" ng-disabled="true"></td>
            <td><input type="number" min="0" ng-model="hr.thu" class="form-control"  placeholder="Hours" ng-disabled="true"></td>
            <td><input type="number" min="0" ng-model="hr.fri" class="form-control"  placeholder="Hours" ng-disabled="true"></td>
            <td><input type="number" min="0" ng-model="hr.sat" class="form-control"  placeholder="Hours" ng-disabled="true"></td>
            <td><span class="form-control">{{hr.sun+hr.mon+hr.tue+hr.wed+hr.thu+hr.fri+hr.sat}}</span></td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</accordion-group>
```